# Compile OpenAL-Soft Code Examples

Tags: c++11, g++, openal, ubuntu-16.04, openal-soft

I just started with **[OpenAL-Soft](https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft/)** and tried to compile the code examples, especially the `alhrtf.c` file using terminal command as:

```
g++ alhrtf.c -o hrtf -lalut -lal -lalc -lopenal -std=c++11
```

I got a bunch of error messages like:

> alhrtf.c:161:28: error: ‘ALC_NUM_HRTF_SPECIFIERS_SOFT’ was not declared in this scope

It seems like I need to link the "hrtf" lib.

So my question is, what compiler flags do i have to set?

I'd be very grateful for some help.

**Reference:**

- link to the script location: [alhrtf.c](https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft/blob/master/examples/alhrtf.c)
- I am on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: provide commands executed and error messages found. Try to be clear on your question and actually make a question.

Comment: Sorry for the bad first post. I tried to compile with: g++ alhrtf.c -o hrtf -lalut -lal -lalc -lopenal -std=c++11 and got a lot of error messages like: " alhrtf.c:161:28: error: ‘ALC_NUM_HRTF_SPECIFIERS_SOFT’ was not declared in this scope " .

Comment: no need to be sorry, I´ve edit your question with information you provided.